# Difference between find and closest in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand the difference between find() and closest() in jquery. Following is my simple code with jquery. ***This is just a dummy form. I just want to understand the difference between them. So don't think what am I going to do with this simple form. ***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunction(){
    var form = $("div#d1").find("form").attr("action");
    var form1 = $("div#d1").closest("form").attr("action");
    alert(form+form1);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="d1">
<p id="p1">Click on this paragraph.</p>
<p id="p2">Click on this paragraph.</p>
<form id="f1" action="aaa">
<input type="text" value="submit">
</form>
<form id="f2" action="bbbbb">
<input type="text" value="submit">
</form>
<form id="f3" action="ccb">
<input type="text" value="submit">
</form>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="myFunction()">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on my submit button, `var form1` value is showing as undefined. Can anyone tell me why it is showing as undefined? Also when I should use closest() and find().

Comment: `closest()` looks up the tree, `find()` looks down.

Comment: [Always read the plaque](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: @MatthewJohnson so if i place a form tag above the div, will it show a value for var form1?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`closest()` is to go up the tree, into the parents, including the current element. `find()` is going down the tree looking in the childs, and the childs of childs:

```
var form1 = $("input").closest("form").attr("action");
```

Comment: so what i need to do if i want to get a value for var form1 in my function? Where should i place the form tag in my code?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález could you please modify the above code in such a way that i could get values for both var form and var form1

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. 3 forms? 1 input for each form? and a submit button outside the forms.. Anyways, I've updated my answer with an example for `closest`

Comment: Thanks. !! I am just trying to understand the concept of closest and find.

Comment: they are the complete opposite, that's all :) It's like climbing a tree versus falling out of it

Answer (score 4):

**[FIND](https://api.jquery.com/find/)**

> Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of
>   matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

**Example:**

`$(selector1).find(selector2)` search the decedent of the `selector1` element and return ***all elements*** that match `selector2`.

**[CLOSEST](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that
>   matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up
>   through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

**EXAMPLE**

`$(selector1).closest(selector2)` selects the element `selector1` and then traverses the dom upwards and returns the ***first element*** that matches the `selector2`

Answer (score 2):

[closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

[find](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Closest will go up in parent elements to find a match to the selector.

Find will go down into child elements to find a match to the selector.

Both will first test the initial element before going through parent/child elements.

Comment: so what i need to do if i want to get a value for var form1 in my function?

Comment: @sreehari - what are you trying to do with those two forms?  Your set up doesn't make sense.

Comment: this is just to understand the difference between closest and find. I have seen a lot code in my project where they are using find and closest. So i just wanted to know the difference between them and when i should use them

Comment: @sreehari - you should read the examples on the documentation pages I linked to.