# Closest Image from li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to animate only the menu icons. If I remove the `closest('img')` it animates the whole li.

This doesn't work:

```js
//animate menu icons
$('.nav-item').hover(function() {
  console.log('entered');
  $(this).find('img').toggleClass('animated swing');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">

    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="dashboard">
                <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
                <span class="menu-title">Dashboard</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="general-setup" onclick="gitLabFetch()" id="createEnviromentTab">
                <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
                <span class="menu-title">Create Environment</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#docker-pages" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="testing-pages">
                <img src="../resources/img/icons/docker-icon.png" alt="">
                <span class="menu-title">Docker <i class="fa fa-sort-down"></i></span>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="docker-pages">
                <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="docker-status">
                            <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
                            <span class="menu-title">Container Status</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="container-creation">
                            <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
                            <span class="menu-title">Container Creation</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="docker-logs">
                            <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
                            <span class="menu-title">Container Logs</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="docker-console">
                            <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
                            <span class="menu-title">Container Console</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="docker-images">
                            <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
                            <span class="menu-title">Images</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="docker-volumes">
                            <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
                            <span class="menu-title">Volumes</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="docker-info">
                            <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
                            <span class="menu-title">Information</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: As `img` is children use `.find('img')` instead of `.closest('img')` and I think you need `toggleClass('animated swing')` instead of `.removeClass('animated swing').addClass('animated swing');`

Comment: Please update the snippet I made for you with the CSS you have

Comment: What is the meaning of this line ? `.removeClass('animated swing').addClass('animated swing');` Why do you remove then add same thing ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287626/difference-between-find-and-closest-in-jquery

Comment: this doesn't work well. I will post all my code.

Comment: please check my code again. when I have a dropdown menu they all toggle except the one that is being hovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is structured in such a way that you have `.nav-item` nested inside `.nav-item`. The `<li>` element is a block level element and in your dom hierarchy you have one large block level element (the third `<li>` from your example) on which you apply a hover. In this one block level element there are many images (which happen to be inside other `.nav-item` and perhaps this is confusing you). This large hover area created by the third `<li>` is causing all of the nested images to toggle.

To fix your specific example, you can isolate each `hover` action to the `.nav-item a` selector before doing the `find` operation to get specific child images for each anchor instead of each list item.

```
$('.nav-item a').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('img').toggleClass('animated swing');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```js
//animate menu icons
$('.nav-link').hover(function() {
  console.log('entered');
  $(this).find('.menu-image').toggleClass('animated swing');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">

    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="dashboard">
                <img class="menu-image" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
                <span class="menu-title">Dashboard</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="general-setup" onclick="gitLabFetch()" id="createEnviromentTab">
                <img class="menu-image" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
                <span class="menu-title">Create Environment</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#docker-pages" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="testing-pages">
                <img class="menu-image" src="../resources/img/icons/docker-icon.png" alt="">
                <span class="menu-title">Docker <i class="fa fa-sort-down"></i></span>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="docker-pages">
                <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="docker-status">
                            <img  class="menu-image" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
                            <span class="menu-title">Container Status</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="container-creation">
                            <img class="menu-image" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
                            <span class="menu-title">Container Creation</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="docker-logs">
                            <img class="menu-image" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
                            <span class="menu-title">Container Logs</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="docker-console">
                            <img class="menu-image" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
                            <span class="menu-title">Container Console</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="docker-images">
                            <img class="menu-image" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
                            <span class="menu-title">Images</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="docker-volumes">
                            <img class="menu-image" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
                            <span class="menu-title">Volumes</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="docker-info">
                            <img class="menu-image" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
                            <span class="menu-title">Information</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to animate.

Comment: i have target menu-title class. if you hover on menu title then it will animate.

Comment: i want to hover on li, not title